# Xamarin Forms MasterDetailPage in MasterDetailPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail, hamburger-menu

Is there a way to put a MasterDetailPage into the Detail of another MasterDetailPage with having the "Hamburger"-Button visible inside the Master NavigationBar of the Detail view?

My approach:

```
Current.MainPage = new MasterDetailPage
  {
    MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover,
    Master = new ShellPage
    {
      //ParentPage = this,
      Title = "Einstiegspunkte",
      Icon = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ? "Hamburger.png" : null // Device.OnPlatform<string>("Icon-Small.png", null, null)
    },

    Detail = Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone ? new NavigationPage(cp)
    {
      Title = "ListPage",
      //Icon = Device.OnPlatform<string>("tab_about.png", null, null)
    } : new NavigationPage(new MasterDetailPage()
    {
      Master = new NavigationPage(new ListPage(ep))
      {
        Title = "ListPage"
      },
      Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage
      {
        Content = new Label
        {
          Text = "Hallo erstmal"
        }
      })
    })

  };
```

This results in two NavigationBars at the top. The first shows the "Hamburger"-Button. I also tried to hide the first NavigationBar, what works great, but then I can not see the "Hamburger"-Button.
Anyone tried that already?

Comment: i don't believe it's possible to directly next two `MasterDetailPage`s. You'll either have to find a platform agnostic solution with xamarin forms or resort to using a custom view with a custom renderer

Comment: I believe that Hamburger menu in masterdetailpage  designed for page navigation, if you need another hamburger menu for different purpose, i think you should make separate menu.